# how to get a list of files that were checkout out but then the pending changes were undone

Tags: tfs

My team are using team foundation server.

I think I have done an 'undo pending changes' on a file that I have made changes to.

1) Is there a way to see a list of files were the pending changes were undone?

2) Is it possible to do an undo 'undo pending changes' **from within
TFS**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have actioned an 'undo pending changes' then there is no way to recover those files as they are overwritten by a 'get latest'.
Once a pending change is undone then the status of the file being checked out to you is removed and it is as if you never touched it.

Comment: Ok, I realise now there is no way to recover the file. 
If I can get a list of files that were checked out and then undone I could maually go through them and hopefully remember why the changes were undone.

Comment: As far as I know once you have done the undo the status is cancelled and you cant determine the files that you 'did' have checked out.  It really is as though you never touched them.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to look at the file dates and times on disk (within your workspace).  When TFS "gets" items, the local file always has the date/time the file was got.

This won't get you your changes, but it might get you the list of files you're looking for.